# Subset data based on first occurrence of a status flag

Tags: r

My data looks like this:

```
dfin <- 
ID   TIME   CONC   STATUS
 1    0      5      0
 1    1      4      1
 1    2      3      0
 2    0      2      0 
 2    10     2      0
 2    15     1      0
```

I want to subset the `dfin` for the first occurrence (for each `ID`) when `STATUS==1` and `TIME > 0`. If the subject `ID` has no `STATUS==1` recorded at any time, then I need to subset the last raw of that subject.

the output here should be:

```
dfout <- 
ID   TIME   CONC   STATUS
 1    1      4      1
 2    15     1      0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way with `dplyr`, we can `group_by` `ID` and check if there is any row which satisfies our condition (`STATUS == 1 & TIME > 0`), if it is then we get the first row which satisfies the condition using `which.max`, if there is no such row then we just return the last row using `n()`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(ifelse(any(STATUS == 1 & TIME > 0), which.max(STATUS == 1 & TIME > 0), n()))

#     ID  TIME  CONC STATUS
#  <int> <int> <int>  <int>
#1     1     1     4      1
#2     2    15     1      0
```

---

Another approach using only base R. This actually follows the same logic as in `dplyr` but `ave` returns length same as input so we keep only `unique` values and take cumulative sum (`cumsum`) over it to get corresponding rows from the data frame.

```
df[cumsum(unique(with(df, ave(STATUS == 1 & TIME > 0, ID, FUN = function(x) 
         if(any(x)) which.max(x) else length(x))))), ]

#  ID TIME CONC STATUS
#2  1    1    4      1
#5  2   10    2      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach with `data.table`.  Convert the data.frame to 'data.table' (`setDT(dfin)`), grouped by 'ID', `if` there is `any` 'STATUS' as 1, then get the logical expression where 'TIME' is greater than 0 or `else` get the last row (`.N`) and subset with `.SD`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dfin)[,  .SD[if(any(STATUS == 1)) STATUS == 1& TIME  > 0 else .N], ID]
#   ID TIME CONC STATUS
#1:  1    1    4      1
#2:  2   15    1      0
```

It can be also written as

```
setDT(dfin)[, .SD[(STATUS == 1 & TIME > 0)| (!any(STATUS) & seq_len(.N) == .N)], ID]
```

#### data

```
dfin <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), TIME = c(0L, 1L, 
 2L, 0L, 10L, 15L), CONC = c(5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L), STATUS = c(0L, 
 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -6L))
```